# How to run a shell file in Apache Spark using scala

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to execute a shell file at the end of my code in spark using scala. I used count and groupby functions in my code. I should mention that, my code works perfectly without the last line of code.

```
(import sys.process._
/////////////////////////linux commands
val procresult="./Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/seprator.sh".!!)
```

could you please help me how to fix it.

Comment: I'm _pretty_ sure that the exception is not from the code. I _think_ that your query uses `groupBy` and `count` operator or function (see `partial_count(1)`). And `Scan ExistingRDD` makes me think you use Kafka as the source for a streaming query (Structured Streaming). How much am I wrong?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: You are correct. I thought that it is because of my Spark version or something else! now what should I do?

Comment: Can you paste the entire stacktrace? I don't think you're showing us the most relevant part. Thanks!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Found the solution. As there was problem in my data set and this problem occurs when I added the mentioned code in my program. Sorry about that and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `sys.process._` package from Scala SDK and use DSL with `!`:

```
import sys.process._
val result = "ls -al".!
```

Or make same with `scala.sys.process.Process`:

```
import scala.sys.process._
Process("cat data.txt")!
```